# Spring Boot - how do I get the base url of a request

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm running a spring boot and a few of my domain services need to know the domain name.

I know that I could capture it at the application layer in the controller method like this:

```
 @RequestMapping(value="/myMapping",method = RequestMethod.POST)
 public ModelandView myAction(HttpServletRequest request) {

 }
```

OR that, if I were running a traditional web application with a war that I could configure a listener like this:

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

And access it like this:

```
((ServletRequestAttributes) RequestContextHolder.currentRequestAttributes()).getRequest()
```

But I do not want to pass around arguments like I would if I captured it at the controller, and I am not running a war with a web.xml.

How can I have my cake and eat it too?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is what I did:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;

import org.springframework.util.Assert;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestAttributes;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.context.request.ServletRequestAttributes;

public class RequestFetcher {
    public static HttpServletRequest getCurrentRequest() {
        RequestAttributes requestAttributes = RequestContextHolder.getRequestAttributes();
        Assert.state(requestAttributes != null, "Could not find current request via RequestContextHolder");
        Assert.isInstanceOf(ServletRequestAttributes.class, requestAttributes);
        HttpServletRequest servletRequest = ((ServletRequestAttributes) requestAttributes).getRequest();
        Assert.state(servletRequest != null, "Could not find current HttpServletRequest");
        return servletRequest;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

If you use Spring Security, you could store this info in SecurityContext.  The trick is getDetails() method, you can put anything you want in there.  I personally use a custom object that stores basic info I need for the current user.  This example just puts a simple string representing your domain:

```
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.security.authentication.AbstractAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContext;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter;

@Component
public class DomainInterceptor extends HandlerInterceptorAdapter {

    @Override
    public boolean preHandle(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, Object handler) {
        String domain = null; // TODO extra domain from request here
        SecurityContext context = SecurityContextHolder.getContext();
        AbstractAuthenticationToken authentication = (AbstractAuthenticationToken) context.getAuthentication();
        authentication.setDetails(domain);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Then to retrieve the domain (for the current request) anywhere in your app you'd do this:

```
String domain = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication().getDetails().toString();
```

Comment: You can use ThreadLocal then: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html

Answer (score 5):

I don't know what you mean by "I'm not running a WAR" but the question is tagged Spring-MVC which is for web applications. Anyways this is how you can get the domain of the request. When a browser makes a request it sends the host name as part of the HTTP request header for multi-domain web hosting. For HTTPS, [Server Name Identification](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server_Name_Indication) is the same thing.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/server/path")
public void request(
        @RequestHeader(name="Host", required=false) final String host,
```